# regex for filtering word based on length or by excluding a word in Python

Tags: python, regex, telnet

I have been trying to figure this one out but since I am a neewby at regex I haven't been able. I need to select the right lines of some telnet output which looks like the following:

```
systemstatus get resume    # line to exclude
systemstatus get idle      # line to filter
systemstatus get talking   # line to filter
systemstatus get ringing   # line to filter
systemstatus get outgoing  # line to filter
systemstatus get sleeping  # line to filter
```

As you can see I need to exclude the one with resume and select all others. So I know I could filter by length but I only know how to filter by length bigger than something but not by many lengths. For example: `"systemstatus get \w{7,}"` would exclude the `resume` line but also the `idle` line. So actually I need something that filters lengths of 4, 7 and 8.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

**Note: this must be done in regex because of telnet library.**

Note2: Since it is telnet, I have to keep reading when the `systemstatus get resume` appears (that's what I mean by "excluding") and not stop as I would do when a `systemstatus get idle` comes in. So filtering by "systemstatus get WHATEVER" and then exluding "resume" would stop reading when "resume" comes in. I am using `telnet.expect([], timeout)` of the telnet lib.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better getting... [somehow](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) the `"WHATEVER"` in `systemstatus get WHATEVER` and filter according to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Call `re.findall` with the `re.MULTILINE` switch.

```
matches = re.findall(r"systemstatus get \b(?:\w{4}|\w{7,8})\b", t, re.M)
```

Which returns each match as a list of strings.

**Regex Details**

```
systemstatus get    # literals
\b                  # word boundary
(?:                 # non-capturing group
\w{4}               # find a word of size 4 
|                   # regex OR pipe
\w{7,8}             # find a word of size 7 or 8
)
\b
```

We're matching by word size here because of your requirement -

> I need something that filters lengths of 4, 7 and 8.

---

**Option 2**
Split your multiline string into separate lines, iterate over each line and call `re.match` on each one -

```
matches = []

for line in t.splitlines():
    if re.match(r"systemstatus get \b(?:\w{4}|\w{7,8})\b", line):
        matches.append(line)
```

Comment: Matching by token count is extremely fragile (most of the time).

Comment: @heemayl You mean by word count? That's what OP wanted though.

Comment: Yeah. Wait till that change to _anything_ :)

Comment: @heemayl I understand what you're saying. But this regex should be flexible enough as per OP's requirements.

Comment: @heemayl By the way, I should let you know that your regex only matches sentences that _don't_ have "resume" in them. What if the requirement is extended to a list of words? ;-)

Comment: D'oh...You got me :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You need to add another backslash `\ ` before each `\b` otherwise it will not work. At least on Python 2.7

Comment: @Storo I think you forgot to specify raw strings with r"..."?

Answer (score 2):

With a zero width negative lookahead (`(?!resume(?:\s|$))`) to ensure that `resume` does not come after `systemstatus get`:

```
^systemstatus get (?!resume(?:\s|$)).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AX7tCA/1)

Answer (score 1):

While regular expressions are powerful, they are not really needed here, just split, apply and combine:

```
text = """
systemstatus get resume    # line to exclude
systemstatus get idle      # line to filter
systemstatus get talking   # line to filter
systemstatus get ringing   # line to filter
systemstatus get outgoing  # line to filter
systemstatus get sleeping  # line to filter
"""

lines = "\n".join([line for line in text.split("\n") 
                  if line and not "resume" in line])
print(lines)
```

This yields

```
systemstatus get idle      # line to filter
systemstatus get talking   # line to filter
systemstatus get ringing   # line to filter
systemstatus get outgoing  # line to filter
systemstatus get sleeping  # line to filter
```

Unless, you do not happen to have text like `systemstatusresumesystem get idle` (meaning `resume` without any word boundary), there's no need for the overhead of a regex engine.

---

**Timing** the different approaches (a 100k each) yields

```
print(timeit.timeit(noregex, number=10**5))
# 0.28622116599945 s

print(timeit.timeit(regex, number=10**5))
# 0.5753898609982571 s
```

So the non-regex solutions needs only **half the time**.